# How to add additional douane costs on magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.1.5

The products which I use to send from Europe and China to Africa, at moment I don't pay any douane costs.
But in the future maybe I will have to pay it for that.

I would like to know if there's anyway to implement something like percentage over the products prices?

Or what is the best way to calculate the additional douane costs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a criteria to calculate additional cost over the products prices in form of Custom Module. In the Custom module you can define the fix percentage value which you want to be applied on the Product prices. You can show and add this additional price to the shipping cost or additional cost at checkout for Delivering the products to Africa. This way you can calculate additional cost on product price and manage it during checkout process. Hope this will help you.